# nested tags SelectNodes c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, tags, nested, selectnodes

I have problem with getting all text from < div class="article-content">, sample:

```
// sample html code: <div class="article-content"> 
//<p>text I want text I want text I want text I want <strong> TEXT I WANT TOO </strong></p><p>text I want text I want text I want text I want <strong> TEXT I WANT TOO </strong></p><div>

foreach (HtmlNode link in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='article-content']/p/text()"))
        {
            if((link.InnerText.Count() == 1) || (link.InnerText.Count() < 250 && link.InnerText[0] == ','))
                test.Text = test.Text + link.InnerText.Trim();              
            else
                test.Text = test.Text + "\n" + link.InnerText.Trim();                              
        }
```

I want have all text in textBlock in the same order as on site but I really don't know how to do it.

Comment: Is htmlDocument an instance of HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument class?

Comment: Yes, it is. I tried your answer but result is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your XPath to `"//div[@class='article-content']/p"` .

EDIT: [link to working example](https://github.com/st4hoo/HtmlAgilityPackTest)

Comment: Strange, it works for me. How do you load content to that htmlDocument?

Comment: Works! My God I forgot to load app on the device -.- really i did it

Comment: Thank you very much! It was so easy.